# Triple integral over a difficult region

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I need to calculate the triple integral
$$\iiint_B f(x, y, z) dxdydz$$

where $f(x, y, z) = x^2 + z^2$ and $B\subset \mathbb R^3$ is located in the 1st octant, bounded by cylinders $x^2+z^2 = 1,\, x^2+z^2 = 4$ and planes $x = 0,\, y = 0,\, y = 1,\, x = z$.

I have a hard time finding the bounds, can someone help me? At least I believe I'm supposed to integrate $0 \le y \le 1$ and $0 \le x \le z$, but I'm pretty much stuck.

Comment: $x^2+z^2 = 4$, sorry for the typo @Anne Bauval

Comment: How do we know on which side of the plane $x=z$ the solid is? (But nevermind, since $f$ and the other equations are symmetric in $x,z.$)

Comment: It is located in the 1st octant, so $x, y, z \ge 0$

Comment: I don't know man thus I'm asking for help and those are all the instruction that were given in the problem

Comment: Thank u bro I really appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As previously commented, it doesn't matter whether we choose $x≤z$
or $z≤x$, the result will be the same.
$$\iiint_{0\le y\le1,0\le x\le z,1\le x^2+z^2\le4}(x^2+z^2)dxdydz=\iint_{0\le x\le z,1\le x^2+z^2\le4}(x^2+z^2)dxdz$$
$$=\int_{0\le t\le\pi/4,1\le r\le 2}r^3drdt=\frac\pi4\frac{2^4-1^4}4=\frac{15\pi}{16}.$$